# Differential equation with two functions and initial condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone help with differential equation $\rho\,\dfrac{dw}{dt}+ 2w \, \dfrac{d\rho}{dt} = kw^2$, where for $t=0, w=w_0>0$, $\rho = \rho_0>0$ and $0 \leqslant k \leqslant \dfrac{\rho}{2}$. What we can say about functions $w(t)$ and $\rho(t)?$

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the only independent variable is $t$?

Comment: Perhaps a useless remark. I denote by $w'$ the derivative of $w$ with respect to $t$, similarly for $\rho$. If you multiply both sides by $\rho$ on the left you get $\rho^2 w'+2w\rho \rho' = (\rho^2 w)'$. So the differential equation becomes $(\rho^2 w)' = kw^2\rho$, which at least looks simpler. You can go a bit further and set $f := \rho^2 w$, so that the equation becomes $f' = (kw/\rho)f$.

Comment: then @Gibbs $(\rho^2 w)' = kw^2\rho \implies (\rho^2 w)' = k(w^2\rho^4)/\rho^3$  divide

Comment: @Isham Yes you can do some tricks. I do not understand the context so well, so I preferred not to give any other hint.

Comment: t is only indepedent variable